# console.log inside <ErrorMessage> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, formik

Generally, this is how Formik's `<ErrorMessage>` tag is used:

```
  <ErrorMessage
                        name="email"
                        render={(msg) => (
                          <Text style={styles.errorText}>
                            {msg}
                          </Text>
                        )}
                      />
```

Is there any way to console.log and see the error message from inside it? I tried making a separate function which does the printing but calling it instead of `<Text>` doesn't work. Do I have an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<ErrorMessage
  name="email"
  render={(msg) => {
    console.log(msg);
    return <Text style={styles.errorText}>{msg}</Text>;
  }}
/>;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per REACT, ***"At the end its all javascript"***,

So, you can try out this :

```
{(msg) => {
    console.log(msg); // <----- HERE
    return (<Text style={styles.errorText}>
    {msg}
    </Text>)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most consise way of doing this is to call `console.log()` and use the `or` operator with the `Text` component. This will call `console.log` and will render the component - since logging returns `undefined` the second statement will always be executed.

```
 <ErrorMessage
    name="email"
    render={
      (msg) => console.log(msg) || <Text style={styles.errorText}>{msg}</Text>
    }
 />
```

Comment: I get an error that ```An expression of type 'void' cannot be tested for truthinessts(1345)```